# I need vBA coe to replace a list of strings in an Excel sheet with another string

Tags: excel, vba

I need code like this in VBA

```
Sub ReplaceCourseCode()

    if(string in a cell= "john")
             replace string in a cell with "ThunderJohn"
    elseif(string in a cell ="David)
              replace string in a cell with "ThunderDavie"
    else move to next cell
End Sub
```

Comment: What's wrong with the code you posted? Please see [ask] for information on asking a good question.

Answer (score 0):

Either of the two procedures below will do what you want. The second one will work faster because it doesn't reference the worksheet as often as the first, but it also uses a different system of setting up the comparison. You might mix the methods and systems to best suit the environment in which you want the job to be done.

```
Option Explicit

Sub ChangeName_1()

    Const Target As String = "B2:B100"          ' change as required
    Dim Cell As Range

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each Cell In ActiveSheet.Range(Target)
        With Cell
            If StrComp(Trim(.Value), "john", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
                .Value = "ThunderJohn"
            ElseIf StrComp(Trim(.Value), "David", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
                .Value = "ThunderDavid"
            End If
        End With
    Next Cell
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Sub ChangeName_2()

    Const Target As String = "B2:B100"          ' change as required
    Dim Cell As Range
    Dim Txt As String

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each Cell In ActiveSheet.Range(Target)
        With Cell
            Txt = Trim(LCase(.Value))
            If Len(Txt) Then
                If InStr(1, "john,david", Txt, vbTextCompare) Then
                    .Value = "Thunder" & UCase(Left(Txt, 1)) & Mid(Txt, 2)
                End If
            End If
        End With
    Next Cell
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

As with most tasks in VBA, there are numerous different methods that can yield the same result.  Here's a couple...

This one loops through the cells you specify, or you could replace `Range("A1:B3")` with `ActiveSheet.UsedRange` to loop through all "used" cells on the worksheet:

```
Sub ReplaceCourseCode()
    Dim c As Range
    For Each c In Range("A1:B3") 'specify the search range (on the active worksheet)
        If c = "john" Then
            c = "ThunderJohn"
        ElseIf c = "David" Then
            c = "ThunderDavie"
        End If
    Next c
End Sub
```

Or, if you're just looking to automate simple Search & Replace (like <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>) for the whole worksheet, you only need one line of code per search:

```
Sub FindReplace()
    Cells.Replace What:="john", Replacement:="ThunderJohn", MatchCase:=False
    Cells.Replace What:="David", Replacement:="ThunderDavie", MatchCase:=False
End Sub
```

### Further reading:

- [Range.Replace Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-replace-method-excel)
- [Replace Function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/replace-function)
- [RegEx Tutorial](http://analystcave.com/excel-regex-tutorial/)  (a Beginner's guide to Advanced searching)